# What did Kant mean by the term "category" and did the term change meaning with Hegel?

Tags: kant, aristotle, hegel

What does Kant mean by the term "[category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(Kant))" and did the term change meaning with Hegel? I'm not asking about for an enumeration of his categories, but what the term means, therein.

I read the wikipedia article, but it's not super clear because it leaves "understanding" undefined, and I was left wondering how e.g. that term linked to a posteriori knowledge.

Obviously some philosophers are going to use the term differently if not discussing Kant, but e.g. Aristotle or something more contemporary perhaps. But I'm also interested in what Hegelians mean by the term, how its application may differ from how it appears in Kant.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/categories/#KanCon

Comment: well maybe you can do better @Not_Here should i delete the question :

Comment: No I wasn't saying you should delete the question, I don't see anything wrong with it. I was just giving you something else to read that might give you an answer. I haven't spent more than a few days of time studying Hegel so I won't be able to give a full answer to the question.

Comment: Categories of the being are going back to Aristotle. Hegel just expands the way categories are derived but in general accepts the Kantian categories as a base https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being#Hegel

Answer (score 3):

A category is a class. The term "category" implies *classification*. We classify a topic into classes. We categorize a subject into categories. In Western philosophy, the term 'categories' pertains usually to general metaphysics, that is ontology. An ontologist categorizes the kinds of being, such as: substance, quality, quantity, relation, fact, etc. The origin is apparently in [Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being#Aristotle), who laid out his ontology in the *Categories* and later developed it in the *Physics* and in the *Metaphysics*. Many later philosophers discussed the list of categories. The special thing about [Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being#Kant) was that his list of categories was not derived from purely metaphysical considerations, but largely from subjective i.e. epistemological and psychological considerations. [Hegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being#Hegel) continued this tendency. In Hegel's philosophy the very distinctions betweem subjective, objective and absolute become blurred by a to and fro "dialectic" movement of derivation. And while Kant's list contained 12 categories, Hegel's list stretched to about 270 categories.

Comment: Isn't Aristotle's [_Categories_](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/) a logical work? In Aristotlian logic "category" is synonymous with "[predicament](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/37148/2014)." Cf. "[What is the philosophical study of classification called?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/30645/2014)" and [its chosen answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/30707/2014).

Comment: @Geremia Hi. I'm not sure how your comment relates to my answer. What do you mean by "a logical work"? And what does it matter here whether the _Categories_ is a logical work, or not?

Comment: I'm commenting on this: "_In Western philosophy, the term 'categories' pertains usually to general metaphysics, that is ontology._" By "logical work" I mean "a work treating the subject of logic," logic being "[the science of reason (_rationalis scientia_)](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/PostAnalytica.htm#02)," "not so much a science as an instrument of science" ("reply to 2" of [_In Boeth. de Trin._, q. 5, a. I](https://isidore.co/aquinas/BoethiusDeTr.htm#51)). Aristotle's _Physics_ is the science of changeable being (_ens mobile_), and his _Metaphysics_ is the study of being _qua_ being.

Comment: @Geremia There are some logical chapters in the _Categories_, but it is, I think, mostly a classificatory work, which the _Metaphysics_ (whose main theme is substance) carries on.

Answer (score 3):

The *OED* defines "[category](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28877#eid9843575)" as:

> <sup>Greek *κατηγορία* accusation, assertion, predication, abstract noun</sup>
>
> 1. b. Kant applied the term to: The pure *a priori* conceptions of the understanding, which the mind applies (as forms or frames) to the matter of knowledge received from *sense*, in order to raise it into an *intelligible* notion or object of knowledge.

This quote shows the difference between Kant and Aristotle:

> <sup>1829   W. Hamilton in *Edinb. Rev.* Oct. 211</sup>
> The [predicaments](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/37148/2014) of Aristotle are…objective, of things as understood; those of Kant subjective, of the mind as understanding… In reality, the whole Kantian categories must be excluded from the Aristotelic list…as determinations of thought, and not genera of real things.