# Where can I study this in more detail?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, aristotle

I am finding al-Farabi's *Philosophy of Plato and Aristotle* on pages 13-17, paragraphs 1-9, (pages 11-13 in the pdf file linked below), very interesting:

http://traditionalhikma.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Alfarabis-Philosophy-of-Plato-and-Aristotle-Translated-by-Muhsin-Mahdi.pdf

What science is this? Is it a branch of Aristotelian logic? It seems to be more "meta" than simply elementary logic. I cannot find similar discussions as al-Farabi's in books such as Jevons's elementary lessons in logic, for example.

What is the science which al-Farabi is discussing and where can I study it in more detail? Is it Aristotelian metaphysics?

Answer (score 1):

In paragraph 6, al-Farabi describes Aristotle's four causes. The reference on page 134 points to Aristotle's *Posterior Analytics* ii. 11. 94*20-23.

One may also consider survey articles on Aristotle's four causes to guide further study and provide more reference material.  Here are two:

1. Falcon, Andrea, "Aristotle on Causality", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Spring 2019 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2019/entries/aristotle-causality/.
2. Wikipedia contributors. (2019, February 17). Four causes. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 12:08, April 23, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Four_causes&oldid=883754450

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late or out of scope, but I think you might be interested by [Al-Kalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam), which "islamic" rational philosophy (islamic is related to the civilization, not to the content necesseraly). It does build on some grec and hindou philosophies.

Good day